# Using Ruby on Rails, highlight text split across more than 1 line in a pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, highlight

I have a Ruby on Rails application, in which I want to highlight a portion of text in a pdf that can be several lines long. The highlighted pdf should then be saved either in its original file or a new one.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I have tried to use gems like prawn, pdf reader and writes, combine-pdf but I have not been able to come to a working solution.

Comment: Quick google search found me this: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/1036